# Generate xml file with the specific format in C#

Tags: xml

I would like to generate an XML file with the specific format as below:

```
<row>
    <col name="ID">123454</col>
    <col name="Name">Test</col>
</row>
```

I have tried but I'm getting the result like this:

```
<row>
    <col xmlns="ID">123454</col>
    <col xmlns="Name">Test</col>
</row>
```

How can I make it in the same format by renaming the `xmlns` to `name`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Thanks, I have done it already

Comment: You've shown your output. I'm saying show the code that generates the output.